# HTACCESS LANGUAGE SELECTION

Tags: .htaccess, multilingual

I'm developing a website where the language selection is the first part of the url:

for example:

[www.mysite.com/en/whatever](http://www.mysite.com/en/whatever) (English)

For other languages, this part could be, for example:

pt, pt-br, fr, jp, etc.

But, if the user does not enter any language fragments, the url must be rewritten to the English language (default language). So, for example, if the user types:

[www.mysite.com/whatever](http://www.mysite.com/whatever)

The url is rewritten to

[www.mysite.com/en/whatever](http://www.mysite.com/en/whatever)

I'm using the following fragment in my .htaccess file:

RewriteRule ^/?(?!en/|pt/)(.*) /en/$1 [L,R=301]

However, it is only valid for the "en" and "pt" languages and it is working OK.

But, I would like to have an expression that covers all possible languages (including brasilian-portuguese -> pt-br, with 5 characters). And, if there was none in the first part of the url, then the url is rewritten with "en".

Thanks!